# How to call a function from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

this is probably one of the most common question out there, having a FORM1 and FORM2, how I can call a function (on FORM1) like: ***MySQLConnect*** from FORM2. I tried couple of options and I can't get it to work, in the second attempt I tried calling the function from a button, but no luck.

Form1.cs (**My first attempt:**)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
   }

   public void MySQLConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Starting a MySQL connection
   }
}
```

Form2.cs (**My first attempt:**)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   Form1 mainForm;

   public Form2(Form1 mainForm)
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       this.mainForm = mainForm;
       // call function on form1 MySQLConnect()
       mainForm.MySQLConnect();
   }
}
```

---

Form1.cs (**My Second attempt:**)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   public void MySQLConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Starting a MySQL connection
   }
}
```

Form2.cs (**My Second attempt:**)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{


   public Form2()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void btnMySQLConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

      Form1 myForm1 = new Form1();
      myForm1.MySQLConnect(sender, e);
   }

}
```

Please help!

Comment: did you try to `Show` your second form? because I'm pretty sure that your first attempt should work.

Comment: What errors are you getting? As an aside, a function like MySQLConnect should be in a utility class, not a form.

Comment: Try removing parameters from MySQLConnect. i.e. private void MySQLConnect() { ... }.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example works if you pass the parameters expected by MySqlConnect.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   Form1 mainForm;

   public Form2(Form1 mainForm)
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       this.mainForm = mainForm;
       mainForm.MySQLConnect(this, new EventArgs());
   }
}
```

However, I can't imagine what a function named MySqlConnect could do with the parameters passed.
So it is better to remove them in the method definition and do not pass anything when you call it.

And I agree with the comments above. Why do you hide such important (and often required functionality) inside a Form instance? You have to pass this form instance everywhere you need to connect to your database. It is better to prepare some static service class ( in a Database Access Layer) that carry on this job

Answer (score 0):

```
mainForm.MySQLConnect();
public void MySQLConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Any ideas? You just omitted arguments.